# trying to Browse processes with gui using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, hyperlink, multiprocessing, psutil

Im trying to make a program and i need to link two process together. if one of them stoped the other one stops too and for some reason my gui lagging when trying to browse process and check the conditions i made for it.here is the short video from my problem [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OGXy.gif).

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import messagebox
import psutil
import os



class myapp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("test")
        self.win.geometry('200x100')
        self.win.config(bg='black')
        self.win.resizable(False,False)
        self.ctr = 0
        self.tk_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.tk_var.set("0")
        lab=tk.Label(self.win, textvariable=self.tk_var,
                     bg='black', fg='#FF0000')
        lab.place(x=90, y=45)
        btn = tk.Button(self.win,text='test',command='',
                        bd=0,bg='#7E1600',width=10,
                        activebackground='#6D0000')
        btn.pack(pady=20)
        self.upd()
        self.test()
        self.win.mainloop()

    def upd(self):
        self.ctr += 1
        self.tk_var.set(str(self.ctr))
        self.win.after(50,self.upd)

    
    def test(self):
        self.service = "notepad.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter())
        
        
        
        if self.service != True :
            er = messagebox.showerror(title='error', message='notepad.exe has been stopped')
            if er == 'ok':
                self.win.destroy()
        else:
            self.win.after(500,self.test)
os.popen('notepad')
myapp()
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OGXy.gif)

Comment: Please clarify what should happen with your code, I can't see what you want

[minimal reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AsyncAwait in this code my script constantly checking for a notepad.exe is open or not and if it's not program raise an error and close the app the problem is GUI lagging. just run the code and you'll see the problem.(don't forget to move the window)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still working on my English.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import psutil
import os


class myapp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("test")
        self.win.geometry('200x100')
        self.win.config(bg='black')
        self.win.resizable(False, False)
        self.ctr = 0
        self.tk_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.tk_var.set("0")
        lab = tk.Label(self.win, textvariable=self.tk_var,
                       bg='black', fg='#FF0000')
        lab.place(x=90, y=45)
        btn = tk.Button(self.win, text='test', command='',
                        bd=0, bg='#7E1600', width=10,
                        activebackground='#6D0000')
        btn.pack(pady=20)

        self.upd()
        self.win.mainloop()

    def upd(self):
        self.ctr += 1
        self.tk_var.set(str(self.ctr))
        self.win.after(50, self.test)

    def test(self):
        self.service = "notepad.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter())
        if self.service != True:
            er = messagebox.showerror(title='error', message='notepad.exe has been stopped')
            if er == 'ok':
                self.win.destroy()
        self.win.after(500, self.upd)

os.popen('notepad')
myapp()
```

upd->test->upd->test... just It only takes one call upd. No need to call test. Also, the after function call is wrong. See my modified code. It's hard to explain in my short English.

Comment: still the same if you grab the box and move it around you'll see the lag

Answer (score 1):

I renamed some functions in my example for better understanding...

I see that your check is too fast, which can cause lag on lower computers, also, keep in mind that when you call the 'check_notepad' function when initializing the class, whenever you click on the 'test' button it adds a new check , that is, another check loop comes into action and this cascades making your app increasingly heavy in memory...

My solution, in addition to some improvements in the code, is just to start the checker once, so as not to create cascades of checks, and from that your app does not lag anymore, if you need to leave it 'on' using a checkbox instead of a button can do more sense...

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import psutil


class myapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # styles
        self.geometry('200x100')
        # vars
        self.timer = 500
        # widgets
        self.tk_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        lab = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.tk_var)
        lab.place(x=90, y=45)

        self.check_var = tk.BooleanVar()
        btn = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Test', variable=self.check_var)
        btn.pack(pady=20)

        # Starts
        self.update_label()
        self.check_notepad()

    def update_label(self):
        self.tk_var.set(self.tk_var.get() + 1)
        self.after(self.timer, self.update_label)

    def check_notepad(self):
        if self.check_var.get():
            if not notepad_is_open():
                er = messagebox.showerror(title='error',
                                          message='notepad.exe has been stopped')
                if er == 'ok':
                    self.destroy()
        # call back loop
        self.after(self.timer, self.check_notepad)


def notepad_is_open():
    service = "notepad.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter())
    return service


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not notepad_is_open():
        os.popen('notepad')
    myapp = myapp()
    myapp.mainloop()
```

[image: Example gif]

Comment: Still i can see the problem. if you check the check button and grab the window and move it around you can see the lag. @AsyncAwait

Comment: Edit my answer with example gif, not lagging for me.

Comment: [for me is lagging](https://imgur.com/a/GGif5s6) @AsyncAwait

Comment: @AsyncAwait are you sure you gave me the same code you pasted here ? because I gave the code to my friend to run it and the problem is still there (i9 13th 13900kf - RTX 4090)

Comment: yes, same, and tested now on my old laptopcore i5 3230 no lag too